# Difference between Viper, Vimpulse and Evil for Emacs?

Tags: emacs, viper-mode, vimpulse, evil-mode

I have recently started using Emacs after using Vim for a long time now (like many others out there), and I personally feel that Vim movement keys and text objects are one of the best things an editor can have. I heard about emulating these features in Emacs using the different plugins, but after reading a bit more on the internet, I'm confused.

I have come across three modes specially: **Viper**, **Vimpulse**, and **Evil**. Can someone please help me out with understanding how to use these modes to achieve a near perfect Vim emulation? Do I need to install all three of them? What is the difference between them? Thanks.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Simply put:

- **Viper**: Basic Vi emulation mode offered by Emacs; in-built and comes bundled with Emacs
- **Vimpulse**: Adds on to the Viper mode but offering advanced features like visual selection and text objects
- **Evil**: A completely new Vim emulation mode for Emacs and is said to be the successor of both Viper and Vimpulse mode. This mode is said to be much better than both the above combined and users report facing lesser problems with this. Recommended going forward.

The instructions to install Evil can be found [here](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil). Good luck!

Comment: [According to EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Vimpulse), Vimpulse was made entirely obsolete by Evil Mode, which started as a fork of the former: "In February 2011, Frank Fischer proposed to merge the Vimpulse and vim-mode projects. Frank’s initiative culminated in a new project, Evil." Vegard Øye, the then-maintainer of Vimpulse, is still current maintainer of Evil Mode.

Comment: Regarding the differences between Viper and Evil, [EmacsWiki's entry on Evil](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil) quotes from a discussion, although the exact source is unclear: "The main difference is that while Viper emulates classical vi, Evil emulates Vim. It therefore sports additional features like Visual selection and text objects. Evil also attempts to integrate with Emacs: for example, repetition is implemented in terms of keyboard macros. At the most basic level, Evil is just a collection of key bindings that can be extended and adapted to any Emacs mode."